# Receiving a value of data that has the most recent date in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table in SQL Server 2008 like:

```
FId     Status    StatusId  StatusDate
---------------------------------------------------
1     Scheduled     4       2010-06-19 00:00:00.000
1     Completed     3       2010-07-19 00:00:00.000
1     Queued        2       2010-04-19 00:00:00.000
2     Queued        2       2010-02-19 00:00:00.000
2     Removed       1       2010-03-19 00:00:00.000
```

What I want is to receive the final `StatusId` for a `FId`.

For example, my output should be like:

```
FId     Status    StatusId  StatusDate   
---------------------------------------------------
1     Completed     3       2010-07-19 00:00:00.000
2     Removed       1       2010-03-19 00:00:00.000
```

So there would be only one row for each `FId`, and the `statusID` is the one belong to the most recent `StatusDate`. How can I do that?

I try (not working the where part):

```
Select 
    s.Id as FId, st.Status, st.Id as StatusId, sh.StatusDate
from 
    StatHistory sh 
inner join 
    Request s on sh.Request_Id = s.Id
inner join 
    Status st on sh.Status_Id = st.Id
where 
    sh.StatusDate = (Select MAX(sh.StatusDate) 
                     from StatHistory sh2 
                     where sh2.Request_Id = sh.Request_Id)
```

I feel I am close but couldn't finalize it. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is almost fine.  You have a typo in the subquery:

```
Select s.Id as FId,st.Status,st.Id as StatusId, sh.StatusDate
from StatHistory sh inner join
     Request s
     on sh.Request_Id = s.Id inner join
     Status st
     on sh.Status_Id = st.Id
where sh.StatusDate = (Select MAX(sh2.StatusDate)
------------------------------------^
                       from StatHistory sh2
                       where sh2.Request_Id = sh.Request_Id
                      );
```

You have written `MAX(sh.StatusDate)`.  That references the column in the *outer* query.  And (assuming the value is never NULL), it will always be true.

There are, of course, other ways of writing the query.   To be honest, I don't know if `row_number()` would be faster than your method, particularly if you have an index on `StatHistory(Request_Id, StatusDate)`.

Comment: damn I missed that :)

Comment: @Eray . . . This is the type of mistake that one tends to make *once*.  After experiencing the "pain", you'll use and see the table references much more easily.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want to do:

```
SELECT A.FId
    , A.Status
    , A.StatusId
    , A.StatusDate
FROM
      (SELECT s.Id AS FId
           , st.Status
           , st.Id AS StatusId
           , sh.StatusDate
       FROM   StatHistory sh
            INNER JOIN Request s ON sh.Request_Id = s.Id
            INNER JOIN Status st ON sh.Status_Id = st.Id) AS A
      INNER JOIN
              (SELECT s.Id AS FId
                   , MAX(sh.StatusDate) AS StatusDate
               FROM   StatHistory sh
                    INNER JOIN Request s ON sh.Request_Id = s.Id
                    INNER JOIN Status st ON sh.Status_Id = st.Id
               GROUP BY s.Id) AS B ON A.FId = B.FId
                                 AND A.StatusDate = B.StatusDate;
```